# webPack error when use webpack -d --mode development --watch

Tags: webpack

After updating webpack to version 5, my project gives the following error

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.devtool should match pattern "^(inline-|hidden-|eval-)?(nosources-)?(cheap-(module-)?)?source-map$".
```

my webpack configuration is

```
const configPublic = {
  entry: {
    Public: './scripts/Public/Public.js',
    Setting: './scripts/Public/Setting',
    Home:'./scripts/Public/Home.js'
  },
  
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/scripts/Public'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
    }]
  }
}
module.exports = [
  
  configPublic
];
```

Comment: Are those complete details? Share full error details and webpack. It seems you have added an unsupported option.

Comment: That's the error text, I didn't add anything. I just upgraded the packages and after that it gives this error.